Possible to combine and/or compare a swept Sine and a wide band noise signal?
I am working on a problem where two profiles need to be compared.
One is a swept sine in $m/s^2$ (Acceleration) and the other is a sine-on-random signal composed of a swept sine $m/s^2$ and a random wide band noise as a APSD (Acceleration Power Spectral Density) in $((m/s^2)^2/Hz)$ with changing spectral densities over the frequencies. I did some research and found a Formula to convert from an amplitude spectrum $A_{FFT}(f)$ to a PSD spectrum $ A_{PSD}(f)$:
$A_{PSD}(f) = A^2_{FFT}(f) /2Δf$ , with the frequency width Δf used in the FFT.
My plan was to convert all the amplitude spectra to PSD with that formula, add the one swept sine to the random noise (making a sine-on-random) and compare it to the other swept sine as PSDs.
Now my questions:

Does my approach make sense?
If not: how would I go about to make them comparable in terms of severity if they were applied to a mechanical component?


I think you have it backwards. The source I found uses the formula $X_{aggregate}(f) = \sqrt{2\Delta fX_{PSD}(f)}$. https://blog.endaq.com/how-to-calculate-a-better-fft-by-leveraging-the-psd-method

you are right, sorry for the confusion! Tank you! I'm changing it in the original post.

I’m not sure on specific scalings of acceleration PSDs, but you will likely need to scale by the number of datapoints as well.
